# Error in Code Newbie to Sql

Tags: sql

Can you please tell me what is wrong with the code

```
CREATE TABLE VISIT
PET_ID NUMBER (25),
VET_ID VARCHAR2(20),
VISIT_DATE DATE,
BASIC_COST NUMBER (8,2),
SYMPTOM VARCHAR2 (80),
TREATMENT VARCHAR2 (25),
);
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Perhaps Oracle?)

Comment: (25), extra comma at the end?

Comment: You've got comma to many, and missing a parenthesis. Also, if you get an error, why not share the error message?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE VISIT` must be `CREATE TABLE VISIT(`

Answer (score 1):

First the opening bracket '`(`' is missing, ie `CREATE TABLE VISIT (` .

Second '`,`' not required after the last column, ie `TREATMENT VARCHAR2 (25)`.

```
CREATE TABLE VISIT (
PET_ID NUMBER (25),
VET_ID VARCHAR2(20),
VISIT_DATE DATE,
BASIC_COST NUMBER (8,2),
SYMPTOM VARCHAR2 (80),
TREATMENT VARCHAR2 (25)
);
```